# Argument of type '(action: User & TypedAction<"login start">) => void'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm new in typescript and I'm learning state management in angular11. When I create my effect it give me an error **Argument of type '(action: User & TypedAction<"login start">) => void'**.

I have tried like this

```
  login$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(loginstart),

      //   Argument of type '(action: User & TypedAction<"login start">) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: User & TypedAction<"login start">, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
      //   Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'
      exhaustMap((action) => {
        console.log(action);
      })
    );
  });

Action
const LOGIN_START = 'login start';
export const loginstart = createAction(LOGIN_START, props<User>());

export interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}
```

How can I solve this??

Comment: You should return observable inside exhaustMap

Answer (score 1):

It's basically because you are not returning Action from Effect.

```
      @Effect()
  login$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(loginstart),

      //   Argument of type '(action: User & TypedAction<"login start">) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: User & TypedAction<"login start">, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
      //   Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'
      exhaustMap((action) => {
        console.log(action);
        return of(someAction)
      })
    );
  });
  constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}
```

Where returned action could be whatever you want:

```
export const someAction = createAction('login start success or something');
```